# Apply a fucntion with lambda to Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have 2 time-series and I would like to find the nearest date from each date in time-series1 to time-series2. I found how to do it separately per date, but I would like to apply it to the entire time-series1. They are in two different dataframes called `o` and `p`

This is how my data looks like:
Time-series1:

```
o['date']
>>>0    2020-01-26
1    2020-01-28
2    2020-01-31
3    2020-02-15
4    2020-02-17
        ...    
86   2021-01-10
87   2021-01-20
88   2021-01-27
89   2021-01-30
90   2021-02-14
Name: date, Length: 91, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Time-series2:

```
p['date']
>>>1     2020-02-17
3     2020-03-02
4     2020-03-03
5     2020-03-04
6     2020-03-05
         ...    
172   2021-01-30
173   2021-02-06
174   2021-02-07
177   2021-02-12
179   2021-02-14
Name: date, Length: 144, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

The function that I use:

```
def nearest(pivot,items):
    return min(items, key=lambda x: abs(x - pivot))
```

Which works on a separate singular date, for example:

```
nearest(o['date'][6], p['date'])
>>>Timestamp('2020-03-02 00:00:00')
```

When I try to apply it to the whole `pandas Series` I get an error:

```
o['date'].apply(nearest, args=(p['date']))
>>>---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-82c86ffd48ff> in <module>()
----> 1 o['date'].apply(nearest, args=(p['date']))

C:\Users\ran\Anaconda3\envs\main\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds)
   4180 
   4181         # handle ufuncs and lambdas
-> 4182         if kwds or args and not isinstance(func, np.ufunc):
   4183 
   4184             def f(x):

C:\Users\ran\Anaconda3\envs\main\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __nonzero__(self)
   1325     def __nonzero__(self):
   1326         raise ValueError(
-> 1327             f"The truth value of a {type(self).__name__} is ambiguous. "
   1328             "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."
   1329         )

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I feel that there is something basic I'm missing.

I guess I can do:

```
[nearest(x, p['date']) for x in o['date']]
```

But I would like to know how to apply it to a `Pandas Series`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Series.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) with lambda function:

```
s = o['date'].apply(lambda x: nearest(x, p['date']))
```

Or with `args` parameter:

```
s = o['date'].apply(nearest, args=(p['date'], ))
```

Numpy alternative with [`numpy.argmin`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmin.html) should be faster:

```
a = o['date'].to_numpy() 
b = p['date'].to_numpy()
pos = np.argmin(np.abs(a- b[:, None]), axis=0)

s = pd.Series(b[pos], index=o.index)
```

Comment: Thanks - `s = o['date'].apply(lambda x: nearest(x, p['date']))` that was the basic thing I was missing